# Groups agents on the basis of particular value in the agenset

Tags: netlogo

**GIVEN :** Given an agentset of turtles where each turtle has patch it wants to move, in the next time step(tick).

**PROBLEM :** Two or more turtles may have the same patch set which they want to move to

**TO SOLVE :** then I have decide depending upon another parameter of the turtles as to which one will move to that patch and rest stay still.

**CONSTRAINT:** Thus, Each patch has only one allowed turtle.

How do i code this, agentset doesn't have the necessary functionality like remove duplicates etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say that "agentset doesn't have the necessary functionality like remove duplicates," but there are, by definition, no duplicates in [NetLogo agentsets](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#agentsets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `table` extension. Looping the the turtles with `ask`, create a table mapping patch coordinates to a list of turtles wanting to move there.  Write a `resolve-conflicts` reporter that picks one turtle from such a list.  Walk through the table using `resolve-conflicts` to pick one turtle for each target, and move that one to the target patch.

I wish the `table` extension should add a `groupby` primitive.  This need is pretty common.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list of all variables containing the destined patch of each turtles (let's say this turtle variable is called *next-patch*). Then you loop through the list and if one patch appears twice (if j = i), you ask the turtle with *next-patch* = i to choose another patch.